# How can we open Apple TV store from AppleTV App

Tags: swift, swift3, tvos

I have a requirement where i need to force upgrade my Apple TV app when new version is available. But unlike mobile apps AppleTv does not have safari to open web view in my app. How can i redirect user to AppleTV store from my Apple TV app.

Any ideas would be of great help.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Have you tried `UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(yourURL)`?

Comment: yes i have tried it. Below is my code snippet:

let appStoreURL = NSURL(string: "https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/wee-puzzles/id1035425291?mt=8")

 UIApplication.shared.openURL(appStoreURL! as URL)

Comment: it worked fine when running on TV.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with `UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(yourURL)`

For tvOS that URL contains a special prefix `com.apple.TVAppStore`, it would be something similar to the following example for Youtube:

```
com.apple.TVAppStore://itunes.apple.com/us/app/youtube-watch-upload-and-share-videos/id544007664?mt=8
```

As a summary, this code would allow linking directly to the Youtube application on the AppStore.

```
let appStoreURL = NSURL(string: "com.apple.TVAppStore://itunes.apple.com/us/app/youtube-watch-upload-and-share-videos/id544007664?mt=8")
UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(appStoreURL, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)
```